# Spark Scala flatMap over bson document with subdocument from Mongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and Scala. I have a Mongo collection with documents like this:

```
{
    "_id": "doc_1",
    "posts": {
        "a": { "total": 1 },
        "b": { "total": 2 }
    }
}
```

I'm loading this into a Spark RDD like this

```
val rc = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "my_collection"), Some(ReadConfig(sparkSession)))
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sparkContext, rc)
```

I would like to use [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@flatMap[U](f:T=%3ETraversableOnce[U])(implicitevidence$4:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) (or another suitable function) to flatten out the posts subdocuments into a new RDD like this:

```
|--------|---------|-------|
| doc_id | post_id | total |
|--------|---------|-------|
| doc_1  | a       | 1     |
| doc_1  | b       | 2     |
| doc_2  | ...     | ...   |
|--------|---------|-------|
```

(I'm using an RDD rather than a DataFrame because the documents are large and this appears to use less memory).

The signature of flatMap is `flatMap[U](f: (T) => TraversableOnce[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]`. Each object in the RDD is an `org.bson.Document` from the Mongo connector, so I want to write something like:

```
val newRdd = rdd.flatMap( { x: org.bson.Document => { x.posts }})
```

But this gives:

> value posts is not a member of org.bson.Document

I've done a lot of Googling.  Seems like this should be simple but I can't figure it out.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you try explode function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not JavaScript :) You must use only fields that are in the class; JavaScript notation is not allowed.

As I can see, `Document` has the function `get`, which you can use:

```
case class Post (///...
val newRdd = rdd.flatMap( { x: org.bson.Document => { x.get("posts", Post)// do something }})
```

Where instead of `// do something` you should post your transformation.